# WooCommerce import csv for tax rate issue

Tags: wordpress, csv, import, woocommerce

I want to upload different csv files for different tax rates.
First of I created the different tax rates.
WooCommerce default comes with `standard rates` so I created `6%` and `21%`

I prepared the `.csv` files based upon the example WooCommerce provides while using the export function.

If I want to upload my `6%` rates it does upload but places everything in the `standard rates` table. I can't get them to upload to the `6%` rate table.
If I do the same with the `21%` they just get applied to the `standard rate` table. So everything (`6%` and `21%`) is in the `standard rates` table.

I can't get this to work. Is there anyone who has the same problem?
I tripple checked my `.csv` file and as far as I can see this is correct.

Here is my csv header (in Dutch):

```
Landcode,Staatcode,Postcode,Plaats,Tarief %,Belastingnaam,Prioriteit,Samengesteld,Verzendmethoden,{Belastingklasse this wasn't there}
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it working.

In case anybody else runs into this problem!

For some reason my WooCommerce "demo"-file didn't had a column called `Tax Class`.
So they all got placed in the `standard rates` table.

After I added the column everything worked fine.
I created one big `.csv`-file containing all rates and uploaded that.